# xml is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, xml

I have been going crazy about this for a couple hours. Can someone help me? I am getting "xmlDoc is not a function" error.

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;  
loadXMLDoc();

function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
  var item = "Bonnie Tyler";
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var x = xmlDoc('ARTIST').find(includes(item));
  console.log(x);
}
```

Comment: what did you expect from `xmlDoc('ARTIST')` ??? how look your XML ( for this part) ?

Comment: you can check it from here https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried nearly everything works for NodeJS but found a solution by using xml2js package. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
function myFunction(xml) {
  var item = "Bonnie Tyler";
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var x = [...xmlDoc.querySelectorAll('ARTIST')].find(el=>el.textContent == item);
  console.log(x);
}
```

your xmlDoc is xml document, not a function, you can only apply some methods on.

Comment: Thanks but now I am getting this "document must contain a root element."